# How to delete a service from k8s?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a service running in `minikube` cluster:

```
$ kubectl get service
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   4s
```

I tried to delete the service:

```
$ kubectl delete --all services --all-namespaces
service "kubernetes" deleted

$ kubectl get service
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   2s
```

It is deleted but it restarts by itself. I have deleted all pod and deployment. But what makes the service restart? How can I delete the whole service?

Comment: Try setting replicaSet to zero or you can also try deleting deployment if not required. kubectl autoscale rs <replicaSetname> --max=0 --min=0

Answer (score 3):

You can not delete the `kubernetes` service. Even if you delete it it will be re-created by kubernetes control plane. This service points to Kubernetes API Server pods and does not make sense to be deleted by users because that can render many other critical components that depends on this service non-functional.